# DOMDocument::load in PHP 5

Tags: php, xml, memory-leaks, loops

I open a 10MB+ XML file several times in my script in different functions:

```
$dom = DOMDocument::load( $file ) or die('couldnt open');
```

1) Is the above the old style of loading a document?

> I am using PHP 5. Oppening it
>   statically?

2) Do I need to close the loading of the XML file, if possible?

> I suspect its causing memory problems because I loop through the nodes of the XML file several thousand times and sometimes my script just ends abruptly.

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a DOM parser, the whole XML document is loading in memory -- which can lead to problems when working with a big document *(I know, you probably don't have much of a choice)*

First of all, I would try not to open the same document more than once :

- it means more work for PHP : it has to parse a big document several times, and, each time, build the DOM tree in memory
- it might require more memory -- In theory, when leaving the function in which you instanciated the `DOMDocument` object, its destructor should be called, and memory released, but, who knows...

About the "*Is the above the old style of loading a document*", well, looking at the documentation for [`DOMDocument::load`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php), it seems it can be called both dynamically *(see the example)* and statically *(see the return value section)* ; so, I suppose both solutions are OK, and there is no "old way" nor "new way".

What do you mean by "*my script just ends abruptly*" ? Do you have a Fatal Error about `memory_limit` ?

If yes, if you can change that kind of configuration setting, it might help to set [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) to a higher value.

Comment: Thanks for that info! The script just dies, no warning no nothing. In apache, it just kills off the child process after the httpd.exe process reaches 250MB of RAM usage. I think its a memory leak and I need to close the documents loaded. Is it ok to just use unset()?

Comment: Well, you can try (PHP doesn't always deal with memory as well as one would like), but I'm not sure it'll help much : 10 MB of XML means a **big** document, that is not that easy to load :-(

Comment: @Abs : I am also trying to parse xml files > 250 MB. Is there any way to increase this 250 limit?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [**strong text**](http://bugs.php.net/41479) concering memory leaks in DOMDocument. When I was parsing huge xml files (90MB) I used read file line by line and parse it with regualar expression. It's ugly, I know, but it worked without with quite low memory.